# How to check the status of a Broadcast Variable in Spark Execuctors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am interested in tracking the status of a broadcast variable in Spark. I would like to know how much memory the broadcast variable is consuming in each executor while the task runs, and confirm it has been unpersisted after .unpersist() is called upon completing the task. Is this possible?

Comment: Trying log it though your code is an option?